# How to use parameters in Laravel Eloquent Eager Loading functions?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I need to run a select on multiple database tables using `Laravel 5.6` and I get parameters from the post `$request`.

I want to do something like this, but this is wrong:

```
Casefile::with([
    'client',
    'loan' => function($query) {
         $query->where('bank_name','REGEXP',$request->bank_name)
    },
    'section'
])->where($find)->get();
```

In this example the `$request` will be an undefined value, but earlier it is defined and has value.

What is the correct way to do this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `$request` available inside the closure:

```
function($query) use($request) {
```